Enclose Network termination box and Router in cabinet
My broadband cable termination device is mounted on a hallway wall. Its unsightly and has Router ethernet and power cables running above it.
What is the simplest way to DIY a cabinet only about 150mm deep to enclose it all?
As it is not very deep, it may be unlikely to find a readymade for mounting on a wall over existing equipment.

A picture would help a lot.

If you have wood stud walls faced with drywall, build a vented cabinet to fit between the studs and route your equipment into the cabinet.

If you can find a cabinet whose face size and appearance you like, but which is too deep, you could brings us a picture of that and ask something like "how can I cut this cabinet to make it shallower and mount over existing equipment?"

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact dimensions would help too!

Such things ARE made, though the cleaner install is one that mounts into the wall between studs. You may even be able to pervert a "medicine cabinet" intended for a bathroom to serve the purpose - obtain one from habitat restore or some other used house equipment source to make it a bargain. But things for exactly that job are made if you want to buy new.
e.g.

Image source, no endorsement implied.
It's simple enough to DIY such a thing - build a box the correct width to mount in between your studs and otherwise large enough to hold your networking detritus. 4 boards will do, joints can simply be screwed together; or glued, or you can dovetail them if it brings you joy. Screw it in place. Preferably move the cables into the wall as well. Put a door, or a picture, or a mirror on the front of it. If the network equipment gets hot, leave some gaps for ventilation, or add some holes for ventilation.
If you want to surface mount it, [perhaps you have a masonry wall?] you can certainly do that, it just takes up more space in the hallway. If you want to buy a 150mm/6 inch deep wall cabinet premade, those are also commonly available on a quick look. You might need to add some vents and drill some holes for cables, of course.
If you have surface mounted cables above the network equipment, you could extend the cabinet to the ceiling, or put bookshelves above and/or below the covering or door that hides the equipment and hide the cables behind books.
